# Explanation/interpretation of the parameters in the spaCy config file

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I have a couple of questions regarding the parameters that we define in the `config.cfg` file. Although spaCy's docs do try to explain them, I feel that the explanation isn't really descriptive enough and that lots of things are scattered around the docs, making it difficult to find exactly what you need, especially with spaCy v3, (unless I'm looking at wrong parts of the website) which is recent and hence has really less question/answers in the forums.
I'm basically building a Named Entity Recognition (NER) model along with a transformer component. My questions are as follows:

1. In the following part (same question for `corpora.train` also), what is the difference between `max_length` and `limit`?

   For `max_length` the docs say "Limitations on training document length"
   For `limit`, the docs say "Limitation on number of training examples"

   Aren't they both more or less the same thing? I mean I can limit the number of training examples by limiting the document's length itself, right?

```
[corpora.dev]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.dev}
max_length = 0
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null
```

2. In the below snippet, what is the meaning of one 'step'? I understand `max_steps=0` means infinite steps. But how do I know how many such 'steps' make one epoch? Also how many example sentences are covered in 1 such step?

```
[training]
train_corpus = "corpora.train"
dev_corpus = "corpora.dev"
seed = ${system.seed}
gpu_allocator = ${system.gpu_allocator}
dropout = 0.1
accumulate_gradient = 1
patience = 1600
max_epochs = 10
max_steps = 0
eval_frequency = 200
frozen_components = []
before_to_disk = null
```

3. How exactly is the `learn_rate` being modified in the below snippet of code, during the training process? More specifically, what do `total_steps` and `warmup_steps` mean?

```
[training.optimizer.learn_rate]
@schedules = "warmup_linear.v1"
warmup_steps = 250
total_steps = 200
initial_rate = 0.00005
```

4. Finally, in the CLI output of the training process, What exactly is this '#'? It was mentioned in one of [GitHub discussions](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/7450#discussioncomment-487000) that *"The # column is the number of optimization steps (= batches processed)"* , but what exactly is this 1 batch or 'optimization step'? If the training process shows me the scores for after 200 such 'batches' how do I interpret it (as in how many example sentences have been processed till that point)?

Comment: You really should split this into multiple questions, it's hard to answer you when all these unrelated questions are together.

Comment: @polm23 I removed the unrelated queries from this question.

Comment: This is honestly still too many questions, please see this. It's OK to have several small, focused questions. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the following part (same question for corpora.train also), what is the difference between max_length and limit?
> For max_length the docs say "Limitations on training document length"
> For limit, the docs say "Limitation on number of training examples"
> Aren't they both more or less the same thing? I mean I can limit the number of training examples by limiting the document's length itself, right?

These are different things, you seem to be confused about what a "document" is. You can think of a "doc" as being a single object in spaCy. Different docs don't know anything about each other. A doc is based on a single string.  Using normal Python strings as an example:

```
["cat", "dog", "fish"] # this is three strings
["cat dog fish"] # this is one string
```

You can see that "take three strings from the list" and "take strings not more than three characters long" are very different things. The values in spaCy are like that.

> In the below snippet, what is the meaning of one 'step'? I understand max_steps=0 means infinite steps. But how do I know how many such 'steps' make one epoch? Also how many example sentences are covered in 1 such step?

A "step" is a "batch". A "batch" is running training over some number of examples and updating the model weights once. You can control the size of a batch so it can be any number of examples. An "epoch" is how long it takes the training to see every example once, so if you have 5 documents per batch and 30 training documents then 6 steps would be one epoch.

spaCy doesn't necessarily know anything about "sentences" in training, docs are the basic unit of a batch. Your training examples might all be single sentences but that's not a requirement.

These terms are not spaCy-specific, they are widely used in machine learning.

> How exactly is the learn_rate being modified in the below snippet of code, during the training process? More specifically, what do total_steps and warmup_steps mean?

This is from Thinc, [see the docs there](https://thinc.ai/docs/api-schedules#warmup_linear).

To quote:

> Generate a series, starting from an initial rate, and then with a warmup period, and then a linear decline. Used for learning rates.

At the end of `total_steps` the learning rate stops changing.

> Finally, in the CLI output of the training process, What exactly is this '#'? It was mentioned in one of GitHub discussions that "The # column is the number of optimization steps (= batches processed)" , but what exactly is this 1 batch or 'optimization step'? If the training process shows me the scores for after 200 such 'batches' how do I interpret it (as in how many example sentences have been processed till that point)?

A step is the same thing as in #2, it's one batch. Batch size is expressed in docs, not in sentences.

Comment: I'm still confused about the relation between a doc and an example sentence. How many sentences from my input jsonl file would be there in a doc? Is it 1 sentence per doc?

Comment: It depends on how you set up your data, I'd have to see it to say. A doc can contain any number of sentences. When you call `nlp(text)` that makes one doc, no matter how many sentences are in the text.

Comment: Hmm...so I have my dataset in jsonl in the same format as suggested in one of the spaCy example project (NER fashion brands). I then use the `preprocess.py` script to convert the jsonl to `.spacy` format, and this script as I understand, loops over each sentence one by one, preparing a doc each time. I guess it means there would be exactly 1 sentence per doc object?

Comment: Looking at the fashion NER tutorial project, it turns each line in the JSONL into one Doc. It looks like many of the examples in the JSONL are more than one sentence, for example the first two lines in the eval file.

Comment: Ah right! I think there was a misunderstanding among us, between an 'example' and a 'sentence'. While I was saying 'sentence' all along, I was actually trying to refer to an 'example sentence' (aka 1 single line of JSONL file).
The whole answer and discussion clears some doubts/confusion. Thanks a lot!